# How to increase box shadow size using tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox, shadows

Here I faced the challenge to fix the drop shadow size. Default it comes into smaller shadow. But I want more shadow thickness. Please provide better solution to solve this.

MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}
\tcbuselibrary{hooks}%YOU MUST USE THIS FOR <extras last pre> KEY

\begin{document}

\newenvironment{shadowbox}{\par
\begin{tcolorbox}[drop shadow southeast,
enhanced,colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black]
}{\end{tcolorbox}}

\begin{shadowbox}
Economic feasibility cost is oftentimes the determining factor if the organization will move forward with the proposed solution. Differentiating the cost-effectiveness of the proposed solution as it relates with short- and long-term business goals can best facilitate the negotiation. Can the solution be implemented in phases allowing the organization to allocate funding incrementally?

\end{shadowbox}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shadows are configurable with the shadow option *(see page 188 of the version 4.15 manual)*. By example:

```
shadow={4mm}{-3mm}{0mm}{black!50!white}
```

Code:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}
\tcbuselibrary{hooks}%YOU MUST USE THIS FOR <extras last pre> KEY

\begin{document}

\newenvironment{shadowbox}{\par
\begin{tcolorbox}[shadow={4mm}{-3mm}{0mm}{black!50!white},
enhanced,colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black]
}{\end{tcolorbox}}

\begin{shadowbox}
Economic feasibility cost is oftentimes the determining factor if the organization will move forward with the proposed solution. Differentiating the cost-effectiveness of the proposed solution as it relates with short- and long-term business goals can best facilitate the negotiation. Can the solution be implemented in phases allowing the organization to allocate funding incrementally?

\end{shadowbox}

\end{document}
```

[image: capture]

Comment: Thank you very much Andre, it's really fulfill my requirement! Happy new year :)

Comment: Thank you very much, happy new year to you too :-)

Comment: Nice suggestion, is it possible to fix the gradient for the shadow? Please advise.